# How to use pino-transport in nodejs for logs.?

Tags: node.js, pinojs

```js
const pino = require('pino')
const transport = pino.transport({
  targets: [{
    level: 'info',
    target: 'pino-pretty' // must be installed separately
  }, {
    level: 'trace',
    target: 'pino/file',
    options: { destination: '/path/to/store/logs' }
  }]
})
pino(transport)
```

[image]

Why I am getting this error pino.transport is not a function...?

Comment: works for me. you should debug and check whats going on. Check pino version in package json.

ƒ pino(...args)
... 
transport:ƒ transport(fullOptions)
version:'7.6.4'

Answer (score 4):

It is because your project is using pino version 6.x.

Transports were introduced in v7.x or later